# Is this possible with IList

Tags: c#

I have a public class called `Profile`. Very simple model class currently with 2 properties;  `string Name` and `string Fields`. As I develop the project the class will expand but it's not particularly important at the moment.

I have a `Global static IList` of type `Profile` called `Profiles`. I am quite new to manipulating the data in these `IEnumerable` types but I am looking to update one of the properties of a single profile. I have tried the following but I am receiving an object reference not set exception. The following is where I set the property:

```
Profiles.Single(x => x.Name == listBoxProfiles.Text).Fields = textBoxFieldName.Text;
```

The debugger is showing the listbox and textbox text properties both have the correct values so I think that it is the way I am using single that is wrong.

If anyone could shed some light I would be grateful.

Comment: Actually a good question, +1.

Comment: @RoyDictus - "I am receiving an object reference not set exception"

Comment: If add a breakpoint at the line and run only `Profiles.Single(x => x.Name == listBoxProfiles.Text)` in the immediate window while debugging, do you get a profile? Sound like there isn't a profile with a name that matches your value.

Comment: Your Single usage is Ok. Are you sure Profiles, listBoxProfiles and textBoxFieldName are not null and there is no null object in Profiles collection?

Comment: This does nothing to guard against not finding a value.

Comment: @govix - Adam's right - should there be nothing selected by your query against Name - you would expect such an exception. Use some breakpoints to determine whether a Profile is being selected, and try and code defensively against such exceptions. Also look into SingleOrDefault as an alternative. http://weblogs.asp.net/paulomorgado/archive/2010/03/30/linq-single-vs-singleordefault.aspx

Comment: Just check against null references.. you're probably not matching any Profile thus `null.Fields` throws exception.

Comment: @SkonJeet: Cool nick, I admit I misread it...

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I appreciate that I am not safeguarding - I will definitely now take that into account and do more.

@ChristoferEliasson How do I evaluate Profiles.Single(x => ....)? I get an error saying Lamda expression cannot be evaluated.

Comment: @Govix Sorry, my bad! Forgot that you can't use lambda expressions in the immediate window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple amendment to make the code more defensive is all that is required:

```
var profile = Profiles.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == listBoxProfiles.Text);

if (profile != null)
{
    profile.Fields = textBoxFieldName.Text;
}
else
{
    Profiles.Add(new Profile(textBoxFieldName.Text));
}
```

This code will cope with missing values, `SingleOrDefault` expects 0 or 1 items to be returned. It will throw an exception if more than 1 items are found.

If you *know* your code should always have the item you are looking for, then your code will work - but I'd advise against this style of programming in favour of being a little more defensive.

Comment: Thank you for this answer Adam. In response to your last bit, if I can get the expression to update the List then yes I know it will always work. Earlier in the method I check that a valid profile is selected and also that there is something in the textbox.

Your code has worked and I have marked it accordingly - thank you so much for this!!!

Just out of interest I have no idea how the variable profile updates this list? I thought it was just a separate variable. Does the result type make it an instance of the list that then updates it?

Comment: @Govix If I understand you correctly: the variable `profile` (as returned from the list) is just a reference to the underlying object. You update `Fields` on this underlying object, and both the list and the local variable "see" the update because their references point to the same underlying object.

Comment: Thank you so much! That is exactly what I wanted to know. Are all variables returned from methods references or just IEnumerable results?

Comment: I don't want to get into too detailed a discussion, but all reference types are returned from and passed as arguments to methods by reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ewxz6et.aspx